# Does inverse property of a mathematical group require different elements X and Y?

Tags: group-theory, analysis, inverse

I'm reading a textbook that talks about mathematical groups, and I'm currently solving some problems. The textbook asks if these infinite sets are groups. For this set below -- rational numbers under multiplication -- I was confused by the explanation.

> **(j) rational numbers, multiplication**
>
> **i. Does it form a group?**
>
> The rational numbers under multiplication do not form a group because if the identity element is $1$, then  $1\cdot0=0\ne1$, so it cannot satisfy invertibility.

It says that the group doesn't satisfy invertibility, which is where `X operation Y = I`. From my understanding, `1 * 1 = 1`. Doesn't that mean it satisfies invertibility? Or do they have to be different elements? Is the solution wrong?

I'm really confused because the dihedral group 3 (otherwise known as reflection/rotation group of an equilateral triangle) has `I` as the identity element, and `I`'s inverse is also `I`. So the definition of invertibility must not require different elements, right?

Comment: (i) You are correct; an element can be its own inverse in a group. And in every group, the inverse of the identity is itself (but there may be other elements as well: the reflections in the dihedral group you describe are also their own inverses). (ii) The reason they give that equation is that it is *zero* that does not have a multiplicative inverse. The multiplicative identity must be $1$, but $0x=0\neq 1$, so no element can be the inverse of $0$. You are confused because they shouldn’t have used “$1\cdot 0$”, they should have used “for any $x$, $x\cdot 0$“.

Comment: Oh, that makes so much more sense. If you put that in an answer, I can mark as accepted.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: It's called A Geometric Approach to Matrices, but it was rewritten by students so that is probably why there is an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It says that the group doesn't satisfy invertibility, which is where `X operation Y = I`. From my understanding, `1 * 1 = 1`. Doesn't that mean it satisfies invertibility?

Yes, $1$ is an invertible element.

> Or do they have to be different elements? Is the solution wrong?

The final claim is not wrong. The explanation is somewhat misleading though (probably a typo). They don't claim that $1$ is not invertible. They claim that $0$ is not invertible. That's because $x\cdot 0=0$ regardless of $x$ and so $0\cdot x=1$ has no solution. There seems to be a mistake (typo?) when they write "$1\cdot 0=0\neq 1$". It should be "$x\cdot 0=0\neq 1$".